# Does a scanner sweep from the CC identifies hallucinations?

Tags: starcraft-2

does a scanner sweep from a Terran CommandCenter identifies a hallucinated unit?

a possible scenario would be if you try to mislead the terran player with a collosus hallucination to force him to build vikings or another counter unit. As far as i know a scanner sweep detects cloaked / burrowed units but identifies it a hallucination also?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A scanner sweep provides detection in an area, which includes hallucinations. Almost no player will scan your colossi though as long as he didn't scout your base and saw no robo bay at all.

A scan also doesn't change the target priorities of his units, they will still attack hallucinations as if it was a real unit, even if they are identified by ravens/overseers/observers.

Comment: ok, but is the player aware of that it is a hallucination by a scanner sweep?

Comment: He said "A scanner sweep provides detection in an area, which includes hallucinations." That means yes.

Comment: Do you know if the hallucinations will then appear in the same ghostly way they appear to the caster, or will they still look like real units but just say "Hallucination" if you click them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the former.